# Using a separator while building a string

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python and need a hand with using a separator while building a string with a for loop.

I've defined this function:

```
def to_string(my_list, sep = ', '):

    string = ''
    for s in my_list:
        s = str(s)
        string = string + s
    return(string)
```

But I need to be able to separate each list item with ', '. All the methods if tried so far leave a comma after the last item when printed.
This is for a uni task, so I'm not able to use any built in functions other than str() and range()

edit: forgot to mention we cant use string methods, list methods and slicing. Also, we HAVE to use a loop.

Answer (score 2):

If your list contains items of `str` type then

```
SEPERATOR = ", "
SEPERATOR.join(MY_LIST)
```

If your list contains integer items or non-list types

```
SEPERATOR = ", "
SEPERATOR.join(map(str,MY_LIST)
```

Eg:

```
In [4]: a = [1,2,4,5,6,7]

In [7]: map(str,a)
Out[7]: ['1', '2', '4', '5', '6', '7']

In [8]: ", ".join(map(str,a))
Out[8]: '1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7'
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by Hitesh Dharamdasani is definitely what I'd recommend that you use in real code. If, however, you're not allowed to use the `str.join` method (because your class is trying to teach you to do what it does on your own), I suggest modifying your current code to treat either the first or the last item in the list differently from the others.

For instance, you could initialize your `string` variable to the first item of the list (rather than an empty list), and then loop on the rest of the string (skipping the first item), concatenating the separator followed by the next item each pass through the loop. Or, you could start with an empty string and add all but the last element to the string, each followed by a separator, and then (after the loop ends) add the last element by itself (with no separator after it).

For both of those solutions, using a slice of the list is probably the easiest way to go. That would look like `my_list[1:]` or `my_list[:-1]`. Another approach would be to use the `iter` and `next` functions to get an iterator from the list and then take out the first item, then use the iterator in a `for` loop to go over the rest of the items. This would require some exception handling to work correctly on an empty list though, which might be beyond what you've learned so far.

Comment: forgot to mention we can't use slicing, string methods or list methods